# How to show status commit in readme.md at GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've a Jenkins configured which runs a build when a change is pushed. It works fine and the commit status appears (at the branch tab, at a pull request, etc...)

I'd like to show the status of the commit at the readme.

I've used the plugin "Embeddable build status" but It shows the status of the latest build performed, i.e., if I push a new branch foo, the status at the readme in the master shows the status of branch foo.

Has GitHub something to show the commit status at readme? As it does at the branch tab, where it shows the status of each branch.